# How to prevent DB from getting updated outside of the transactional method while including spring-session-jdbc

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-transactions, spring-session

I have an issue with the behavior of, how spring transaction works. I am not clear on how to implement it correctly. The issue is present only when I am including the dependency `spring-session-jdbc`.

- I am using Spring Boot 2.2.6
- with Hibernate/Mariadb
- Spring security enabled with `InMemoryUserDetailsManager`

I have a method which is annotated as `@Transactional(readonly=true)` and returns the Collection of entities. After receiving the collection from that method, before dispatching, I set some variables to different values for not displaying or change the representation of it. **The issue is, after output is dispatched, the database values are automatically updated**.

To summarize the issue, I have created a basic SpringBoot 2.2.6 project and below are the content.

**Customer.java**

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "customers")
public class Customer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private Integer age;
    private Integer batch;
    private String secret;

}
```

**CustomerRepository.java**

```
@Repository
public interface CustomerRepository extends JpaRepository<Customer, Integer> {

    Page<Customer> findByBatch(Integer batchId, Pageable pagaable);
}
```

**CustomerService.java**
To be noted, in this service class, the method is annotated with `@Transactional(readOnly = true)`.

```
@Service
public class CustomerService {

    @Autowired
    private CustomerRepository repo;

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public Page<Customer> findAllCustomers() {

        Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(0, 10);

        return repo.findByBatch(4, pageable);
    }
}
```

**CustController.java**

```
@Controller
public class CustController {

    @Autowired
    private CustomerService service;

    @GetMapping("/")
    public ResponseEntity<Page<Customer>> indexPath(Model model) {

        Page<Customer> customers = this.service.findAllCustomers();

        model.addAttribute("customers", customers);
        // setting null before sending to client
        // this is for demonstration purpose only
        customers.getContent().forEach(i -> i.setSecret(null));

        return ResponseEntity.ok(customers);
    }
}
```

**Dependencies in pom.xml**

- spring-boot-starter-data-jpa
- spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf
- spring-boot-starter-web
- spring-boot-starter-security
- mariadb-java-client
- lombok
- spring-session-jdbc

And to populate the database below are some SQL insert statements.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `customers` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `age` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `batch` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `secret` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM; // changed to InnoDB basedon @M.Deinum comment

INSERT INTO `customers` (`id`, `age`, `batch`, `name`, `secret`) VALUES (1, 94, 4, 'Ravi', '23423424234');
INSERT INTO `customers` (`id`, `age`, `batch`, `name`, `secret`) VALUES (2, 32, 4, 'Silva', '3424252432');
INSERT INTO `customers` (`id`, `age`, `batch`, `name`, `secret`) VALUES (3, 18, 4, 'Rahul', '322342424');
```

**Sample Project in Github**

I have created this as a simple project which reproduces the issue and uploaded it in Github in this URL https://github.com/imuneer/sprintboot-db-issue.

By simply commenting out the `spring-session-jdbc` in pom.xml make the project work as expected; no any value which I update in my controller is modifying the actual database values. But when the `spring-session-jdbc` is uncommented, it works the opposite.

I am confused here.

1. Why adding the `spring-session-jdbc` changes the behavior of spring transaction
2. Am I missing anything in the first place, so that the program behaves differently in both scenarios?
3. Or my understanding is wrong? If so what is the correct way to keep the collection detached from the persitence context before modifying to the client.

Comment: Your `@Transactional(readOnly = true)` is just in the scope of method `public Page<Customer> findAllCustomers() `.  Could you test moving this to the controller?

Comment: I moved to the Controller method. Still, it is behaving the same way. My confusion is, why this happens only after including `spring-session-jdbc`. What makes the transaction to misbehave here?

Comment: Interesting question @BlueBird. It is not the answer, but normally, I would have a different object to return via the Controller, just like a DTO. Like this way I hide all information that I don't want to be visible. But unfortunately I can't help you with the problem.

Comment: Thanks @PatrickSantana, I prefer to use a DTO. But my real object has like 9 columns and other 3 relational objects which includes their own columns. Really I don't know how easily I can copy these to another DTO. Please advice.

Comment: First of all you shouldn't be changing your entity but rather use a projection (or dto) to display/return only what you want (instead of retrieving everything). Next you are using MySQL and looking at your config with MyISAM tables which don't support transactions at all. Switch to InnoDB table types to support transactions properly.

Comment: Yes, @M.Deinum that I switched to `InnoDB` now. But the behavior in the transaction has no change. But home come the issue is linked with spring-session-jdbc? Any idea?

Comment: Right now I am using projection @M.Deinum. But still, my confusion part is the behavior of transaction, before and after the addition of Spring session JDBC